# What is the usage of references and pointers to constants?

Tags: c++

In C++ Primer book I read about references to constants such as these:

```
const int ci = 1024;
const int &r1 = ci;
```

The same goes for pointers.

```
const double pi = 3.14;
const double *ptr = &pi;
```

I wonder, what is the usage of these references if you can't even change the value of the constant? Why would you even want to create pointer to a constant?

Comment: *"Why would you even want to create pointer to a constant?"* Take `const char *s = "foobar";`. That's a pointer to a constant. Would you say it's useless?

Comment: Lets say you have a very large structure, for example a `std::vector<int>` of 10000 elements. Lets say you want to pass it as argument to a function, but the function should not change the contents of the vector. Now, would you pass it by value and let the whole vector be copied every call you make? Or would you pass it by reference without any copying of the vector data?

Comment: There are also other places where references or pointers are useful in C++, most notable for polymorphism. But for the simple examples you show, there's no need for the reference or the pointer.

Comment: this example is to simple so in this case `const double *ptr` is useless.

Comment: One purpose of programming language semantics is to help developers to avoid errors while expressing their intent. A `const` reference or pointer allows you to express the fact that you want to pass a reference to some data which shouldn't be changed.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder, what is the usage of these references if you can't even change the value of the constant

The most common use case are functions. A function with an argument can be much more useful than a function that only uses a constant.

But passing a constant into a function call (thereby binding the argument to that constant) is also useful:

```
void foo(const int &r1);

// call using a constant
foo(ci);
```

Note that there is rarely a need to use references to integers, as usually one is only interested in the value of an integer, and don't care about the identity of the object.

The indirection that references and pointers provide makes runtime polymorphism possible. You'll learn about that when you study object oriented programming.